# How do I import a node module transpiled from typescript into Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, node-modules, nuxt.js

I have a generated typescript client from Nswag that I want to transpile and use in my Nuxt application.

I transpile my apiService.ts client to apiService.js with a basic tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES6",
    "target": "ES6"
  }
}
```

And import it to my project, I have tried both require and import.

```
import { PersonClient } from "./../services/api/apiService.js";
const apiService = require("./../services/api/apiService.js");
```

The application builds but when I try to load the page with my client I get:

```
exports is not defined
    at Module../services/api/apiService.js
```

I have tried googling around but I just don't know the right question to ask. How can I use my apiService.js?

Viual Studio Code gives me syntax highlighting when I import it to the project, so it should be possible?

Comment: You might need to explicitly transpile into esm format. But maybe it would be easier to just add TS support to your app? https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/. If this doesn't work, try creating a MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I did solve my problem by transpiling into esm format like you said. I followed this guide to do so: [link](https://hackernoon.com/building-and-publishing-a-module-with-typescript-and-rollup-js-faa778c85396) It does not feel very elegant I had to tweak the tsconfig a little, and I have very little experience with tsconfigs, so I will wait and see if anyone has a better solution or guide before I answer my own question. I could make a MRE too, so that the problem is easier to understand.

Comment: Many libraries supply esm out of the box, no special steps necessary, so your case is a little unusual. You sure there is no esm file in the node module’s dist folder? You can tell webpack to always resolve the esm with an extra line of config if it’s there and webpack isn’t smart enough

Comment: I am sure there is an easier way to do this, I would think Nuxt supports esm out of the box. I just don't know how to set it up. Something I had hoped to get it answered here.
Making my application support typescript is also a solution I should look into.